# Reinsert primary key in the same record

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to insert records into a production table.  The problem is that one of the fields needs to be the same value as the primary key.

In the example below, the Insert query is dropping '99' into [AlsoMyID].  But that's just a placeholder.  It needs to be whatever value is going into [MyID].

How do I write the Insert query so that the system will add the same PK value to *both* [MyID] and [AlsoMyID]?

```
Drop table #mylittletable

Create table #Mylittletable (
[MyID] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
[AlsoMyID] int,
[ActualData] varchar(1))

Select * from #Mylittletable

Insert into #Mylittletable values (99,'x')

Select * from #Mylittletable
```

If you're interested in the background, the developer is using AlsoMyID as a linking field so any number of records can be linked together using the original primary key value.  That said, I have no control over the table structure.

Comment: So, do you want that `AlsoMyID` automatically had the same values as `MyID`? You can define `AlsoMyID` as a computed column or write a trigger that would populate `AlsoMyID` on INSERT. Maybe there are other methods as well.

Comment: "the developer is using AlsoMyID as a linking field so any number of records can be linked together using the original primary key value." Many records in the same table? I'm not really following the logic here. IMHO, there's not much point of storing the same value twice.

Comment: Short answer is you can't. Ignoring the non-working code (because you can't provide a value for an identity column without special statements), there is no direct functionality to duplicate the identity values assigned to your inserted rows at the time of insertion. As the others have written, this requires a multi-step process to work without hard-coded values.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, imagine 10 records where `MyID` increments from 1 thru 10 but `AlsoMyID` is a constant 1.  The same value is only stored twice on the first record.  In my situation, I'm not interested in this functionality so I just need them to be the same.  Apologies if that wasn't clear.

Comment: @PowerUser Now that makes much more sense. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: If you can use a `SEQUENCE` instead of `IDENTITY` this is straightforward

Comment: May we assume all records with the same `AlsoMyId` value will be inserted as a batch?

Comment: @ZoharPeled, if I understand you correctly, yes. The `Insert` statement inserted a few thousand records.  My solution was to just leave that field null on the `Insert`.  Then I immediately ran an `Update` to populate it.  I tested in dev first and it all worked out in the end.  If you have an alternative solution, feel free to post.  It might help someone else out.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you cannot specify the value for identity column unless you use set identity_insert on. so according to your requirement, you need to insert the same value to AlsoMyID as MyID.

You can work it out as flowing:

```
insert into Mylittletable
select @@IDENTITY+1,'1'
```

Comment: He/she is not specifying anything on the identity column.

Answer (score 0):

With this trigger on the table you can insert anything on the `alsoMyID`-column and that will be overwritten with what get's set in the `myID`-column.

```
create trigger tr_Mylittletable ON Mylittletable
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
    declare @ID int = (select MyID from inserted)
    update Mylittletable set AlsoMyID = @ID where MyID = @ID
END
```

NOTE: This only works when making inserts of one line at a time!

Comment: This trigger should only be for `INSERT` - if they wanted it for `UPDATE` as well there would be no point in the column. The trigger is currently broken and will fail for multirow inserts/updates

Comment: You're right, it should only be for inserts. Took the update part away